# 24 V alternator to 24 V motor

Tags: capacitor, motor, ac, alternator

I plan to run a 400 RPM, 400 W, 24 V AC alternator through a bridge rectifier, then through a 25 V smoothing capacitor, and then drive a 24 V, low-RPM DC motor.

I would like advice on specifics. Wattage is not a problem.

Comment: Need DC motor info for smoothing capacitor size. 24VAC is in RMS so will have a peak of \$24\sqrt2V\$ which is what the rectified DC will be. Need a transformer to bring the voltage down. Also, I assume brushed DC motor.

Comment: Electronics is *all* about the details. Can't just hack together some parts and hope for the best.  Well one could, but the result would be less than stellar.

Comment: If you need "advice on specifics" then you need to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are referring to a three phase, 24 V ~, 400 W, 400 rpm wind turbine generator, with a permanent magnet rotor, voltage regulator and a bridge rectifier.

The three phase, full-wave bridge-rectified output, with its low ripple voltage, would not require a filter capacitor.

Comment: If the 3-ph generator RMS voltage is 24 volts, the rectified  DC voltage will be about 28 volts. The motor will probably be ok with that. but the no-load speed will be about 17% higher than normal.

Comment: @Charles Cowie - Yes, Charles, 28 V DC would be just right for lead acid battery charging. For the DC motor the regulator may require setting for 24 V DC output.

Answer (score 2):

For a brushed DC motor, you can forget about the smoothing capacitor and connect the rectified and un-filtered DC directly to the motor. The RMS voltage will be 24 volts and probably fine for the motor.